# Multiple nonlinear regression in R (# of restaurants vs # of people in region)

Tags: r, non-linear-regression

I am trying to find the relationship between the number of people that come to a certain region and the number of accommodations, shops, restaurants, and leisure places in that region. I know the number of total people whom visit a certain region but I don't know whether they visit for accommodation or to shop, etc.

So I have plotted the number of restaurants, etc, in each region by the number of people in that region. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9HTz.png) is the graph. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGfCm.png) is some of the data I'm trying to analyze

Thus, the general shape of these points is a parabola that is rotated 90 degrees. I am not very familiar with R and cannot figure out how to find this equation/know if this is not possible.

My goal is to get coefficients of each parameter (ie accomodation, restaurants, etc.) so I can conclude something like "if we add 10 restaurants, an increase of x number of people should come to the region."

Here is a snippet of some code I've tried but not succeeded

```
linez <- nls(People ~ sqrt(Accommodation/a) , data=fourth, start=c(a=1), trace=T)
lines(s, predict(linez, list(x=s)), col = "red")
```

Comment: Having some of your data may help you find an answer; here are some [tips](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) ;)

Comment: well, why don't you transform your X or Y variable and do a simple linear regression instead?